# cannot load such file -- mysql/mysql_api (LoadError)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I get this error while using rails server

```
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql/mysql_api (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
    from E:/ruby/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
    from E:/ruby/bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from E:/ruby/bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I installed mysql by downloading the mysql-controller-c ,but it still reports me an error, and l copied libmysql.dll to ruby/bin ,also I copied it to system32,and it still have the problem,can someone give me a suggestion to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This gem does not have prebuilt native extension for Ruby-2.0 (see `C:\Ruby\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\mysql-2.9.1-x86-mingw32\lib\mysql`). You will have to [build it yourself](http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/07/07/installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it/) or downgrade to ruby-1.9.